# SuiteCRM add a custom search Query

Tags: search, textbox, sugarcrm, suitecrm

I'm trying to figure it out how to create a text box in Products Module where i can put a clients name and with a query i built shows the prices of the product for that client.
I have the query built and the table that relates the accounts with the products all i'm missing is how to do this customize search

Answer (score 1):

Ok guys I figured it out :)
In the include/LisView/ListViewData.php
There's the query handling every data that a module might need for his list
go to this line:

```
$main_query = $ret_array['select'] . $params['custom_select'] . $ret_array['from'] . $params['custom_from'] . $ret_array['inner_join']. $ret_array['where'] . $params['custom_where'] . $ret_array['order_by'] . $params['custom_order_by'];
```

here you see the query getting all rows from current module (products, accounts, contacts, ..) 
since this handles all modules make sure your changes only change the module you want like so:

```
if($this->seed->module_name == "AOS_Products"
     Your changes
```

OffTopic but very usefull in case you need extra info from another table like i did (account) 
use the global variable db
`$accountPrice = $GLOBALS['db']->query("SELECT shipping_address_street as price FROM "
                                        ." accounts WHERE name LIKE '".$array[$try]."'");
            $accountCodePrice = $GLOBALS['db']->fetchByAssoc($accountPrice);`
Cheers

Comment: I found the way to access the database useful for unit tests when importing a file (+1).